# How can I format a label caption?

Tags: vba, excel

Here's what I want to do. I have a caption that changes every time someone uses the app. The caption is a number... and now it appears like a regular number 123456 ... I want to add "," every 3 digits and I really don't know how to do it because the number doesn't have the same number of digits every time... (I want it to be 123,456 instead of 123456 or 1,234,567... and so on). Thanks!

Comment: Why not have a macro on WorksheetChange() event and just calculate where the comma should go? It's quite trivial a function and shouldn't affect the performance if it's called everytime the worksheet changes (You can speed it up based on the columns that affect this calculation, instead of checking it all the time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're setting the caption in code, so you can use VBA's format function to do this:

```
Me.MyLabel.Caption = Format(MyNum, "#,##0")
```